# Python34 - creating a list with substring comparison

Tags: python-3.x

(noobie question )

I've used BeautifulSoup to scrape a list of hrefs. I've then assigned them to a List.  I wish to extract a specific set of them to another List. There are two substrings I can use to differentiate the ones I want - they all start with "dsp" and they have something like "&tab=tabs-1" in them .

How can I transfer only those from MyList[] to MyNewList[]?
I'm used to having a where clause to work with and cant seem to find any reference - I'm assuming it must be pretty basic

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
urls = ['http://dsp.more/&tab=tabs-1&more" ', 'http://no.mat.ch']

new_urls = [ url for url in urls if url.startswith('http://dsp') and '&tab=tabs-1' in url]
print(new_urls)
```

Comment: That's close and I didnt know about the .startswith   The problem is that there are some 'NoneType' types.    I tried: `  for url in alllist:
 if type(url)!= 'NoneType' and url.startswith('dsp'):
  print(url) ` Thinking that the first condition would be evaluated first. But it still gave me the NoneType  (PS, how do I format in the comment?)